# Obtaining total seconds from a datetime.time object

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timedelta

I have a datetime.time object as 02:00:00 i would like to convert it to the total seconds which should be 7200 seconds.

Comment: what's with the `pandas` tag, could you please clarify if this is pandas-specific?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can combine the time with a reference date to get a datetime object. If you then subtract that reference date, you get a timedelta object, from which you can take the `total_seconds`:

```
from datetime import datetime, time

t = time(2,0,0)

ts = (datetime.combine(datetime.min, t) - datetime.min).total_seconds()

print(ts)
# 7200.0
```

---

With `pandas`, I'd use the string representation of the time object column (Series) and convert it to timedelta datatype - which then allows you to use the `dt` accessor to get the total seconds:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'time': [time(2,0,0)]})

df['totalseconds'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['time'].astype(str)).dt.total_seconds()

# df['totalseconds']
# 0    7200.0
# Name: totalseconds, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

you can calculate with using datetime library

```
def time_in_ms():
    from datetime import datetime
    now = datetime.now()
    time_arr = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S").split(":")
    total_time = (int(time_arr[0]) * 3600) + (int(time_arr[1]) * 60) +(int(time_arr[2]))
    return total_time
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this method; the parameter 'time' has to be under the format hh:mm:ss

```
def convert_to_seconds(time):
    # Separate all symbols of 'time'
    separated = list(time)
    
    # Delete all ':' symbols
    for i in separated:
        if i == ':':
            separated.remove(i)
    
    # Join the elements of the list together two by two
    separated[0] = separated[0] + separated[1]
    separated[1] = separated[2] + separated[3]
    separated[2] = separated[4] + separated[5]
    
    # Delete the last 3 elements of the list that are useless now
    for count in range(3):
        del l[3]
    
    # Convert to integers
    for i in separated:
        separated[separated.index(i)] = int(i)

    # Calculate seconds
    seconds = 0
    seconds += separated[0] * 3600
    seconds += separated[1] * 60
    seconds += separated[2]

    return seconds
```

It is a bit longer as the method before, but a bit simpler to understand.