# Cubic Spline with Python

Tags: gekko

1. my date is in an object format therefore I am struggling to convert it into float or integer
2. I am getting errors using the spline function in python.
3. How can I extract a mathematical equation from the spline plot? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try converting the `datetime` to `seconds` with a time difference from the start. Use `timedelta` and `total_seconds()`. Here are additional suggestions on converting a `datetime` to seconds: [Obtaining total seconds from a datetime.time object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68359147/obtaining-total-seconds-from-a-datetime-time-object) and [working with time-series data in Pandas](https://apmonitor.com/dde/index.php/Main/PandasTimeSeries).

Here is example code for a cubic spline with gekko that also uses the spline to find the minimum.

[image: cspline]

```py
from gekko import gekko 
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

"""
minimize y
s.t.     y = f(x)

using cubic spline with random sampling of data
"""

# Function to generate data for cspline
def f(x):
    return 3*np.sin(x) - (x-3) 

# Create model
c = gekko()

# Cubic spline
x = c.Var(value=15)
y = c.Var()
x_data = np.random.rand(50)*10+10
y_data = f(x_data)
c.cspline(x,y,x_data,y_data,True)
c.Obj(y)

# Options
c.options.IMODE = 3
c.options.CSV_READ = 0
c.options.SOLVER = 3
c.solve()

# Generate continuous trend for plot
z = np.linspace(10,20,100)

# Check if solved successfully
if c.options.SOLVESTATUS == 1:
    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(z,f(z),'r-',label='original')
    plt.scatter(x_data,y_data,5,'b',label='data')
    plt.scatter(x.value,y.value,200,'k','x',label='minimum')
    plt.legend(loc='best')
else:
    print ('Failed to converge!')
    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(z,f(z),'r-',label='original')
    plt.scatter(x_data,y_data,5,'b')
    plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

As a cubic spline, there are separate cubic polynomial parameters for each segment of the spline. There is no closed form solution that can be compactly written. Try [polynomial regression](https://apmonitor.com/che263/index.php/Main/PythonDataRegression) if there is a need to obtain a single equation that fits all of the data.

Comment: Thanks,  I now want to replace the x-axis and the y-axis with my actual dataset. How do i do that as the code you provided seems to be generic

Comment: I recommend that you try it, using the example that I posted as a template. If it isn’t working after your best efforts then create a new question on StackOverflow (don’t add to this question).